# Выбрать часть переводов symfony2

Tags: symfony

Стандартный yml файл с переводами вида:

```
symfony:
    is:
        great: Symfony is great
        amazing: Symfony is amazing
    has:
        bundles: Symfony has bundles
user:
    login: Login
```

Получаю список всех переводов в контроллере следующим образом:

```
$translated = $this->container->get('translator')
    ->getCatalogue($language)
    ->all();
```

Вопрос в том, как получить только определённую часть переводов, т.е. как пример только переводы `symfony.is`:

```
[
    'symfony.is.great' => 'Symfony is great',
    'symfony.is.amazing' => 'Symfony is amazing'
]
```

Comment: Попробуйте загрузить просто yml файл через yml parser. Ну или преобразовать массив руками в нужный

Answer (score 0):

Если вы хотите получить только часть переводов - переместите их в отдельный файл с другим именем(называется доменом) (в моем примере это будет frontend):

[image]

Теперь можно получить нужные переводы следующим образом:

```
$messages = $this->container->get('translator')
    ->getCatalogue($language)
    ->all('frontend');
```